# Check, whether an object has class with a certain number in its name

Tags: javascript, jquery, numbers

My situation is the following: I have several classes with names obj1, obj2, ob3 and an output object. When one of obj# is clicked, i want a corresponding text to be added in output object. Here is my code:

```
<div class="obj obj1">Object 1</div>
<div class="obj obj2">Object 2</div>
<div class="obj obj3">Object 3</div>
<div class="output"></div>
```

And JavaScript:

```
function whichObject($obj) {
for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  switch($obj.hasClass("obj" + (i+1).toString())) {
    case "obj1":
      $(".output").text("Object 1");
      break;
   case "obj2":
      $(".output").text("Object 2");
      break;
   case "obj3":
      $(".output").text("Object 3");
      break;
   }
}

$(".obj").on("click", function () {
   whichObject($(this));
});
```

I need the loop because the number of obj# objects may increase over time and I cannot predict a certain amount of obj# objects.

I'm surely missing something or the whole approach is wrong.

Comment: Is this just an example, or do you actually want the text from the clicked element to be inserted as is in the output element?

Comment: It is just an example. I want to apply styles and content based on the clicked object. Later they will be obtained from a database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$('.obj').on('click', function(e){
  $('.output').text(e.target.innerHTML);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="obj obj1">Object 1</div>
<div class="obj obj2">Object 2</div>
<div class="obj obj3">Object 3</div>
<div class="output"></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

So, if somebody is interested I solved it this way:

```
function whichObject(obj) {
  var $obj = $(obj);
  if ($obj.attr("id") === "obj1") {
    $(".output").text("Object 1");
  } else if ($obj.attr("id") === "obj2") {
    $(".output").text("Object 2");
  } else if ($obj.attr("id") === "obj3") {
    $(".output").text("Object 3");
  } 
}

$(".obj").on("click", function () {
whichObject(this);
});
```

while adding the following IDs to my HTML:

```
<div class="obj" id="obj1">Object 1</div>
<div class="obj" id="obj2">Object 2</div>
<div class="obj" id="obj3">Object 3</div>
<div class="output"></div>
```